# Python polytools: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, installation

I am trying to install `symfit` on my Windows machine, running Python 2.7.

It complains that it does not have `polytools`, so I type `pip install polytools` in the command line.

This gives the following error message:

> Could not find a versin that satisfies the requirement polytools (from versions: )
>  No matching distribution found for polytools

What does it mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: "It complains that it does not have polytools" can you expand on this? The only mention on the internet of both polytools and symfit is this question.

Comment: Is this still an issue? I'm the founder of symfit and I haven't experienced or heard of this problem before, but if it is an active issue then your help in improving symfit would be very much appreciated! As suggested by @phd, if this is still relevant then please post this as an issue on our github, including a more complete description of the exact command used and the resulting errors.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It's actually fine, I pip installed and uninstalled a few things a few times until it worked. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polytools module is in [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/polys/polytools.html) and sympy is a [dependency of symfit](https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit/blob/master/requirements.txt). It seems `symfit` doesn't properly declared dependencies. To install its dependencies clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit.git
```

and run

```
pip install -U -r requirements.txt
```

Report the bug at the [symfit issue tracker](https://github.com/tBuLi/symfit/issues).

Comment: Thanks, I did that. 
But now it's saying: "lockfile 0.10.2.post7 has requirement pbr!=0.7,<1.0,>=0.6, but you'll have pbr 4.0.4 which is incompatible."

Comment: Actually I just installed an earlier version of pbr, and now it does not give me any errors from the pip command. However, when I try using symfit (or sympy) in Spyder it complains "ImportError: cannot import name polytools"

Comment: What's the traceback?

Comment: sorry what is a traceback?